# HAProxy - Is there a way to add authentication to stats socket

Tags: haproxy

We would like to use the following line in HAProxy to allow us to enable and disable servers remotely:

`global
  stats socket ipv4@192.168.112.2:1000 level admin`

Is there a way to add basic authentication to this? Or some way to add a username and password for who can access this port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to add authentication to the HAProxy socket.
So as mentioned in this [thread](https://www.mail-archive.com/haproxy@formilux.org/msg19475.html), securing the socket can be done by:
1/ Exposing the socket to a trusted network only(firewalling, ..)
2/ Making the socket listen on a loopback interface and using a ssh tunnel to access it.
3/ Use a HAProxy frontend to access the socket, and then you can secure it with SSL.

Comment: OK, so you're saying I might be able to have a backend that has a server line that points to unix@ as described in https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.7/configuration.html#server ?

Comment: Yep, this works: `server managementport unix@/var/run/haproxy.stat`

Comment: Although securing a TCP connection with Basic Auth isn't possible, so I may have to use SSH instead.

Comment: Ah you are right, you can't use HTTP authentication since the backend is in TCP mode, I have corrected the answer.
Though you can still use client authentication with SSL: https://www.haproxy.com/blog/ssl-client-certificate-management-at-application-level/

Answer (score 1):

You can put the stats bit in its own listen stanza and add auth like:

`listen statistics
  bind :1234
  mode http
  stats enable
  stats uri /stats
  stats realm Statistics
  stats auth username:password`

Comment: We have this now, but it only secures the Web UI stats page, but not the management socket.